# Grid/table in report

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to display data in a basic grid, with borders, column headers, etc. How can this be done in a Crystal Report without having to draw every single line and position/size every field?

I've tried a lot of different things, but it is all so sloppy and time consuming. Isn't there an easy way to just display a table in a grid?

Answer (score 0):

the solution here turned out to not use Crystal Reports. To use alerts in SAP BizOne. It works great for a quick well formatted data subscription case

Answer (score 0):

A **Crosstab** can display results in a footer after the main report has been run. This is the least "time consuming" option, as you put it.

[image]

Otherwise the quickest way to turn an existing report into a "table" is to simply add line elements that span from the header to the footer, dividing your fields into columns. The line elements will resize such that they cover all sections:

[image]